# Aermod output in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, air-quality

I have an aermod output data which has angle (degrees), distance (m) and pollutant concentration from a point (x, y).

How can I create points based on the angle and distance with concentration as attributes in ArcGIS?

Comment: Anglesa s a North bearing, or angles from the source of pollutant? Are there more than one source of pollutants, then you have more than one angle?

Comment: Hello @DelonixR.,
Thank you for seeking the clarification. The angles are from the source with North as 0 degrees and there is only one source.

Comment: Hi, some progress in your work? How is it going?

Comment: Hi @DelonixR.,
Please can you help me?

Comment: edmundo.garron@gmail.com

Comment: @DelonixR.,
Do you want me to send you a mail? Mine is kksfitzgerald@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to proceed with this data is to import it into a spreadsheet  (eg, Excel) and generate a new set of columns with X,Y coordinates rather than polar coordinates as you currently have. The main problem you may encounter is that AERMOD output may contain multiple grid points per line and you need to split that to one grid point per line. Personally, I would do that with a text editor, but it would be easy to do in Excel as well. Getting correct x,y (or easting/northing) is probably easiest in a projected coordinate system like UTM, but that's not essential.

You can then use the Add Data command in ArcMap to open the spreadsheet as a layer, selecting Add XY Data. You will select your new XY columns as the location values. There are plenty of sources on the web that explain how to do this step.

From my limited knowledge of AERMOD, the center reference of the polar grid is not necessarily the source, since the grid system still has to work for multiple sources. However, it is common for single source problems to be set up so that the source is at the origin.